# Custom Post Type filtering by own taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I tried a lot, but with no success. This LOOP works fine. It shows all Custom Post Types (apps-und-tools):

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(
     array(
          'post_type' => 'apps-und-tools',
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
     )
);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<div>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Now I want to filter by a custom taxonomy. First I get the custom taxonomy with `get_queried_object()` and put the `tax_query` to the array in the LOOP. At the end are some control outputs.

```
<?php
// getting custom taxonomy of actual post
$this_term = get_queried_object();
$term_id =  $this_term->term_id;
$term_name =  $this_term->name;
$term_taxonomy = $this_term->taxonomy;
$term_slug = $this_term->slug;

// Wordpress Loop
$loop = new WP_Query(
     array(
          'post_type' => 'apps-und-tools',
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'tax_query' => array(
               array (
                    'taxonomy' => $term_taxonomy,
                    'name' => $term_name
          )
          )
     )
);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<div>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

//Control Output
echo 'term_id: ' . $this_term->term_id;
echo '<br>';
echo 'name: ' . $this_term->name;
echo '<br>';
echo 'taxonomy: ' . $this_term->taxonomy;
echo '<br>';
echo 'slug: ' . $this_term->slug;
?>
```

The result is, that the LOOP does not show any results. No CPTs are shown, but the control output is as expected. I'd just like to filter my CPTs by custom taxonomy.

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this loop to retrieve CPTs.

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => arra('apps-und-tools'),
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => $term_taxonomy,
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $term_slug,
    ),
 ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried, but with the same result. No CPTs are shown, but the control output is as expected.I created the CPT and the custom taxonomies with the metabox plugin

Comment: Did you try to enter the taxonomy name and slug static? The problem can be with queried_object...

Answer (score 0):

```
$term_taxonomy = 'taxonomy_name';
$args = array(
  'post_type' => arra('apps-und-tools'),
  'post_status' => "publish",
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => $term_taxonomy,
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => $search_key,
      ),
    ),
  );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```